# Timestamp value getting modified on receving the response

Tags: java, json, timestamp, timestamp-with-timezone

I'm receiving a Timestamp via API in a `Timestamp`(java.sql) object and after some other validations I'm sending response as a JSON containing that same timestamp value, but the format in which I sent and in which I receive are not the same every time.

For example, if my JSON input has this value:
**Case 1 :**

```json
"interval_time": "2022-01-26T12:00:00.511+05:30"
```

**Reponse**:

```json
{
    "message": "Already contains result for timestamp : 2022-01-26 12:00:00.511",
    "httpcode": 409,
    "documentationLink": "",
    "status": "ERROR"
}
```

Notice the missing `T` and offset value 05:30.

**Case 2:**

```json
"interval_end_time": "2022-01-26T12:00:00.511Z"
```

**Response**:

```json
{
    "message": "Already contains result for timestamp : 2022-01-26 17:30:00.511",
    "httpcode": 409,
    "documentationLink": "",
    "status": "ERROR"
}
```

Notice the missing `T` and offset value got added in the timestamp.

I need a consistent response and it should be exactly what is being sent as an input. No change in timezone or offset.

For Case 1, response should come like this:

**Reponse**:

```json
{
    "message": "Already contains result for timestamp : 2022-01-26T12:00:00.511+05:30",
    "httpcode": 409,
    "documentationLink": "",
    "status": "ERROR"
}
```

and for Case 2, it should be like this:

**Response**:

```json
{
    "message": "Already contains result for timestamp : 2022-01-26T12:00:00.511Z",
    "httpcode": 409,
    "documentationLink": "",
    "status": "ERROR"
}
```

Note: The team is following the ISO 8601 standard.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using java.sql.Timestamp instead of a java.time type?

Comment: You should in theory be using `java.time.OffsetDateTime`

Comment: It' part of an existing codebase. I can switch to java.time. What are the changes I need to make ?

Comment: If you're not in control of the service you're calling, how do you hope to influence its output?

Comment: I'm in control of the service. I will receive the input JSON with a timestamp like I mentioned in the question and I need to setup the response in same format. It's clear enough in the question, not sure what you're asking.

Comment: *For example, If my JSON input has this value :* how do you get that value from `Timestamp`?

Comment: I'm using Gson to parse it to my Java class having a Timestamp data member.

Comment: If it is only for an error case I would provide an additional field for the input timestamp as string and use it in the response. Actually converting it to Java variable only for the database access, not for response.

Comment: *I'm using Gson to parse it to my Java class having a Timestamp data member.* Best to show that code *in the question* There's also [this](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.0/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#setDateFormat-java.lang.String-) having three overloads

Comment: If you were doing it 'manually', you'd produce the json time string with `OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(ts.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault()).toString()` (where `ts` is your `Timestamp`)

Comment: A `java.sql.Timestamp` has no offset information, and the meaning of its `toString()` is sensitive to the current default JVM timezone. It is a bad choice for this.

Comment: @g00se This is working for Case 1 but for case 2 it's giving like this `2022-01-26T17:30:00.511+05:30`
It added the offset in the original timestamp and also displayed it.

Comment: I don't quite understand. By "this", you mean my code showing how to produce `OffsetDateTime` from `Timestamp`?

Comment: Yes..I tried using the same.

Comment: We need to see the code

Comment: Is the requirement to return *the same string* or just *the same date, time and offset*? In other words, if you received `2022-01-26T12:00:00.511000+05:30`, would returning `2022-01-26T12:00:00.511+05:30` without the trailing zeroes on the fraction of second be OK or not?

Comment: Yeah, it would be ok.

Comment: Thanks. In that case parsing into an `OffsetDateTime` is fine and probably what you want to do. IIRC, you need to give Gson an adapter (or similar) to get that to work.

Comment: @OleV.V. Yes, that's correct. I did that only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm receiving a Timestamp via API in a Timestamp(java.sql) object

No, you are not.

You are receiving JSON text containing a string representing a moment in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

Parse the string as a `java.time.OffsetDateTime` class.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2022-01-26T12:00:00.511+05:30" ) ;
```

Avoid the terribly flawed legacy date-time classes such as `java.sql.Timestamp`. Use only their replacement, the *java.time* classes.

To generate text in ISO 8601 format, simply call `OffsetDateTime#toString`.

```
String output = odt.toString() ;
```

> I'm using Gson to parse it to my Java class having a Timestamp data member.

Don’t.

Use only *java.time* classes.

Comment: Thanks @Basil, let me try this and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks @Basil, this is working for me. :)
I switched to java.time library and used OffsetDateTime class everywhere and I'm using Gson only for casting, added a TypeAdapter class and registered it with Gson to make it work.